# Unix jobs command not working well

Tags: unix, ksh, jobs

I have a problem with the command Jobs, because is returning 1 job executing
when all the launched threads (in background) have already aborted.

To know the running jobs, i'm using the command:

jobs | wc -l

Result:
2

When I have only 1 thread (running in background) that command returns 2, instead of one.

Any idea why the command is returning 2 running jobs?

I really dont understand this behaviour, which causing problems with my korn shell script.

```
_check_rfs_thread()
{
```

(...)

```
 if [ $NBR_OF_JOBS -eq 0 ] then 
     # If all threads abort then should exit program here...
     # This is the problem... because a "dummy" jobs keeps "holding on"
     echo "No available threads in 'ready for start' status for process "$PROGRAM_NAME"."
     echo "Check restart_program_status table for process "$PROGRAM_NAME"."
     return 1
 fi
   }
```

(...)

```
_launch_thread() {
 # This function launchs threads in background with &
}
```

(...)

```
SLOTS=15

while [ $LAUNCH_THREAD -eq 0 ]
do

  NBR_OF_JOBS=`jobs | wc -l`
  echo '1 NBR_OF_JOBS: ['$NBR_OF_JOBS']'

  while [[ $NBR_OF_JOBS -ge $SLOTS ]]  # When all threads are available 
  do
     sleep 1
     NBR_OF_JOBS=`jobs | wc -l`
     echo '2 NBR_OF_JOBS: ['$NBR_OF_JOBS']'
  done

  echo '3 NBR_OF_JOBS: ['$NBR_OF_JOBS']'
  _check_rfs_thread $PROGRAM_NAME $SLOTS $NBR_OF_JOBS
  _launch_thread()

done
```

---

The command Jobs returns always 1 job executing, when all my threads are aborted.
Because of that, "if [ $NBR_OF_JOBS -eq 0 ]" is always false ( [ 1 -eq 0 ] )and program keeps executing

```
 - Execution 1 - didint launch any thread:

1 NBR_OF_JOBS: [1]
3 NBR_OF_JOBS: [1]

 - Execution 2 - after launch a thread

1 NBR_OF_JOBS: [2]
3 NBR_OF_JOBS: [2]

 - Execution 3 - a thread gets aborted

1 NBR_OF_JOBS: [2]
3 NBR_OF_JOBS: [2]

 - Execution 4 - no threads to launch and no threads running in
   background

1 NBR_OF_JOBS: [1]
3 NBR_OF_JOBS: [1]
```

Comment: please consider editing your question to include just the plain output of `jobs`. You may be seeing a header or something like that. Good luck.

Comment: The output of the command jobs is: [2] + Running <command unknown>
NBR_OF_JOBS: [2]

Comment: Then it looks like you are having a header. Also, update the question with this info. In comments it is not possible to see exactly how your code looks like.

Comment: `jobs` is a built-in command in the shell. Please update your question to indicate which shell you're using (bash? tcsh?).

Comment: Your updated question implies that the output of `jobs | wc -l` is `"Result: [2] + Running NBR_OF_JOBS: [2]"`. It should be just a number. Please show the exact command you're running and its exact output, and format it as code (highlight it and click the `{}` icon).

Comment: How *exactly* is `$NBR_OF_JOB` set? Can you show us a complete self-contained script that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Does `jobs` work inside shell scripts? My impression is that it only works in interactive shells, not in non-interactive shells.  Also note that processes are not threads, and shells run things as processes, not threads.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: A quick experiment shows that the `jobs` command does work in a ksh script (at least with the `ksh93` shell on my system). It prints `<command unknown>` for the command name, but it appears to print the right number of lines.

Comment: Shouldn't `$SLOTS=15` be `SLOTS=15`? When I run `$SLOTS=15` in ksh, I get `ksh: =15: not found` if `$SLOTS` isn't set, or `ksh: foo=15: not found` if I've done `SLOTS=foo`. Is the code in your question the same as the code you're running?

Comment: Your output needs to be formatted as code, not as a bulleted list.

Comment: Feeding the output of `jobs` to `wc -l` loses all information other than the number of lines. You need to see what the actual output of `jobs -l` is. Try temporarily adding something like `echo ===== ; jobs -l ; echo =====` just before the line that sets `$NBR_OF_JOBS`.

Comment: Thanks Keith Thompson, for the help. i was formatting the code to be more easy to understand

Comment: Make sure you don't break the code when reformatting it. Ideally, your question should include a complete self-contained script/program that reproduces the problem you're having, so that I can copy-and-paste your code, run it on my system, and see the same error you're seeing. Don't make us guess which error are actually in your code and which ones you introduced when re-typing it for the question.

Comment: We can't help you without more information. What is the output of `jobs` *without* `| wc -l` at that point in the script?